# Graph plotting first,second,and third values of variables

Tags: r, dataframe

For example I have this dataset:

```
c1 c2

A 1
A 3
A 10
B 5
B 4
C 3
C 4
C 6
A 5
C 7
```

Is there a short way to maybe plot in 1 graph the first third of values of the A,B,C, the second third of values A,B,C, and the third third values A,B,C. For every variables there will be 3 lines.

So there will be 9 lines in total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_split` and `lapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3), c2 = sample(1:10, size = 9, rep = T))

df %>% 
  group_by(c1) %>%
  mutate(num = 1:n()) %>%
  group_split(num) -> plot_list
  

lapply(plot_list, function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x = num, y = c2)) + geom_line()
})
```

Or you use facets:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(c1) %>%
  mutate(num = 1:n()) %>%
  ggplot() + 
    facet_grid(scales = "free", cols = vars(num)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = c1, y = c2, group = num))
```

[image]